# Python Queue Output Shows More Lines of Output than Expected

Tags: python

I tried out the Python code below (from an online tutorial) in order to learn about queueing threads in Python, but I am wondering why there is a lot more output lines from the producer and consumer functions. I ran the Python code on a Windows machine with i7 cpu core. Output is at https://pastebin.com/NaqpQTvA. Some further questions:

1. The main function indicates maxsize=10 in the pipeline so there should be 20 lines if we count consumer and producers in the output, and if we multiply by 2 for max_workers=2, there should be about 40 lines of output in total right? But I get more than 300 lines of output, not sure why. Are they running on multiple cpu cores or something else going on?
2. Also the consumer output lines are always displaying size=1, but shouldn't they display a range of values between 1 to 10 to reflect the pipeline size?

```
import concurrent.futures
import logging
import queue
import random
import threading
import time

def producer(queue, event):
    """Pretend we're getting a number from the network."""
    while not event.is_set():
        message = random.randint(1, 101)
        logging.info("Producer got message: %s", message)
        queue.put(message)

    logging.info("Producer received event. Exiting")

def consumer(queue, event):
    """Pretend we're saving a number in the database."""
    while not event.is_set() or not queue.empty():
        message = queue.get()
        logging.info(
            "Consumer storing message: %s (size=%d)", message, queue.qsize()
        )

    logging.info("Consumer received event. Exiting")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    format = "%(asctime)s: %(message)s"
    logging.basicConfig(format=format, level=logging.INFO,
                        datefmt="%H:%M:%S")

    pipeline = queue.Queue(maxsize=10)
    event = threading.Event()
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
        executor.submit(producer, pipeline, event)
        executor.submit(consumer, pipeline, event)

        time.sleep(0.1)
        logging.info("Main: about to set event")
        event.set()
```

Comment: By default `put()` will wait if the queue is full and continue as soon there is a free slot. This behaviour can be set by the `block` argument. https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.put

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The queue size limits how many things can be in the queue at one time.  It doesn't limit how many things can pass through the queue.

`producer` keeps adding things to the queue as fast as it can.  If the queue is full, `queue.put` will block until there is room.  As soon as the consumer pulls an item off the queue, the producer adds another item.

Similarly, `consumer` pulls things off as fast as it can until the the event or the queue is empty.

To see what's happening, try using a counter instead of putting random numbers in the queue.  Or try adding a small delay to the producer so it runs slower than the consumer.

```
def producer(queue, event):
    """Pretend we're getting a number from the network."""
    message = 0
    while not event.is_set():
        logging.info("Producer sending message: %s", message)
        queue.put(message)
        message += 1 

    logging.info("Producer received event. Exiting")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with your max workers:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
        executor.submit(producer, pipeline, event)
        executor.submit(consumer, pipeline, event)
```

The producer is filling the queue, and the consumer is emptying it, both going at the same time.

Try changing max_workers=1 and you will see what I mean.  Or leave it at 2 and comment out the execute.submit(consumer...) line and you will see the maxsize obeyed.